# Spring JMS message switching based on type of object

Tags: java, spring, jms

I am maintaining an existing application which receives requests from ActiveMQ and sends responses back to the sender via an ActiveMQ topic. At present there is a single message consumer class which receives messages via a simple DefaultMessageListenerContainer:

```
@Component
public class RequestConsumer {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    JmsSenderService jmsSenderService;

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

        if (message instanceof CustomerRequest) {

            CustomerRequest customerRequest = (CustomerRequest) message;

            Customer customer = customerService.getCustomerById(customerRequest.getId());

            CustomerResponse customerResponse = new CustomerResponse();
            customerResponse.addCustomer(customer);

            jmsSenderService.sendCustomerResponse(customerResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to extend the application to process a number of different requests (e.g. OrderRequest, InvoiceRequest, InventoryRequest, AddressRequest etc.) and send an appropriate response back to the sender. My first thought was to add the functionality to the existing class like so:

```
public void handleMessage(Message message) {

    if (message instanceof CustomerRequest) {

        // deal with CustomerRequest

    } else if (message instanceof InvoiceRequest) {

        // deal with InvoiceRequest

    } else if (message instanceof InventoryRequest) {

        // deal with InventoryRequest
    }
}
```

However this will make the class quite large. I also thought about implementing one queue per request type (e.g. customer.request.queue, invoice.request.queue) and implementing multiple DefaultMessageListenerContainer, one per queue, but this doesn't seem like a great idea either because of the multiple boilerplated classes I'd need to create.

I feel like there must be a way to implement some kind of routing based on the type of incoming object and map it to an object-specific implementation to process the request, but I'm not sure whether this is something Spring/JMS already provides.

Has anyone done something like this before, and if so is there a "Springy" way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to invest some time (as this solution comes with an initial time-investment) then there is an absolutely Spring-conform solution:

**Spring Integration**

This library (a good JMS example [here](http://mujosh.blogspot.hu/2012/09/integratingaccessing-jms-message-queues.html)) has prebuilt and well-tested solutions for all common messaging issues you might face, including the problem you just described above ([message-type based routing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter)).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, looks like Spring Integration will suit my needs.