# Using Spring Integration to route domain objects to the appropriate method

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have recently started looking into Spring Integration as a result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529723/spring-jms-message-switching-based-on-type-of-object/32530353#32530353) and have a question about object-type based routing.

The application I am maintaining needs to process requests from an incoming ActiveMQ queue (request.queue) and send a response back to the caller on a topic (response.topic). At present the requests are structured as follows:

```
public abstract class Request {

    // base class
}

public abstract class CustomerRequest extends Request {

    // base class for customer-specific requests
}

public class FindCustomerByIdRequest extends CustomerRequest {

    private int id;
}

public class FindAllCustomersRequest extends CustomerRequest {

    private boolean includeArchivedCustomers;
}

public class AddCustomerRequest extends CustomerRequest {

    private String name;
    private Date signupDate;
    private Address address;
}
```

I have a service for each high level domain object which provides the functionality to service these incoming requests:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    public CustomerResponse findCustomerById(FindCustomerByIdRequest request) {

        // code snipped

        return customerResponse;
    }

    public AddCustomerResponse addCustomer(AddCustomerRequest request) {

        // code snipped

        return addCustomerResponse;
    }
}
```

I need to route each specific request to the approriate method in `CustomerService` via `@ServiceActivator` which I understand can be done by creating a separate channel for each request and implementing a `PayloadTypeRouter` to place requests on the correct channel based on type.

Over time the list of request types is going to grow, and I am questioning whether a one-channel-per-request setup is efficient/practical/scalable. For example, if there are 100 different request types in the future there are going to be 100 different channels.

What would be great is if I could route the high-level requests of superclass `CustomerRequest` to `CustomerService` and have Spring work out the approriate method to call via an annotation or some other mechanism. Does anyone know if this is possible, or have any comments regarding the many-channels approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no ambiguity, use `<service-activator ... reg="fooBean" />` (no `method`) and the framework will chose the target method based on the payload.

If there is ambiguity (more than one method for the same type), it will fail.

However, a single class with 100+ methods is probably not a good design.

Comment: He mentioned 100 request types, That would need to have 100 service methods in one bean. Nobody would hopefully create such class.

Comment: Good point; totally agree; I just wanted to point out a feature of the framework that may not be understood.

Comment: Sure, I understand. That is why I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Thank you to both for your feedback/answers. The ~100 request types will be distributed across ~20 domain objects; there won't be a class with 100 methods unless I am feeling malevolent to future maintainers :). I will use the functionality described by Gary Russell to map incoming request to service tier, and advice from Ikrnac to split requests into different queues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that your request types are app feature specific. This suggest that you have one queue for all the possible application features. That is horrible idea. You should have at least separate queue per feature.

I suggest to rethink the design of your app.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Are you advocating one queue per request type (e.g. `find_customer_by_id.queue`, `add_customer.queue`) or are you recommending making one queue per domain object (e.g. `customer_requests.queue`, `invoice_requests.queue`)?

Comment: Yes. One generic queue is the same as have HTTP URL in application "example.com/crud-for-everything". Would you do this?

Comment: I get your point about a single queue being a bad idea. What level of granularity would you recommend when implementing queues? For example, a `create_customer.queue`, `delete_customer.queue` or a single `customer_action.queue` and using `PayloadTypeRouter` to route the message to the appropriate `createCustomer` and `deleteCustomer` method?

Comment: hmm, I would say yes. Delete message would for sure have different payload than Create. Therefore It make sense to have different listeners and calling different service methods. When you are writing DELETE and POST methods, it is not mapped to same controller method.

Comment: But bear in mind I am not familiar with your domain, you may have some generic queues if you generalize events in your system for various features (e.g. event delete customer may have same format as delete user).